# what can I do to display the tv shows on the first page?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to create a simple TV shows project and my goal is to display TV shows on the first page. But, every time I run the code it says:

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

What can I do to fix this?

This is my first time working with API. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.

```js
const APIURL = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1';

async function getMovies(){

    const resp = await fetch(APIURL);
    const respData = await resp.json();

    console.log(resp.data);
    respData.results.forEach((shows) => {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = imgPath + shows.image;
    })
    return respData; 
}
getMovies();
```

Comment: Pay attention to the data structure you actually have. Notice, for example, that the word "results" doesn't appear anywhere in it. So why does it appear in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        const APIURL = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1';

        async function getMovies(){

            const resp = await fetch(APIURL);
            const respData = await resp.json();

            console.log(resp.data);
            respData.forEach((shows) => {
                const img = document.createElement("img");
                //img.src = shows.image.medium; // Choose beetwen medium or original
                img.src = shows.image.original  // Choose beetwen medium or original
            })
            return respData; 
        }
        getMovies();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much sir it works after adding      //  document.body.appendChild(img);

Comment: You also don't need the return, if you are not going to use it

Comment: Is there a way to display them with the name of the shows and display them in row and columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">

    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    const APIURL = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1';

    async function getMovies(){
        const resp = await fetch(APIURL);
        const respData = await resp.json();
        //console.log(resp.data);
        const blocks = respData.map((shows) => {
            //const src = img.src = shows.image.medium; // Choose beetwen medium or original
            const src = shows.image.original  // Choose beetwen medium or original
            const name = shows.name
            return `
            <tr>
                <td><img src='${src}' width='250' height='250'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${name}</td>
            </tr>
            `
        })
        return blocks; 
    }
    
    (async() => {
        const blocks = await getMovies();
        const table = document.getElementById('table')

        for (let index = 0; index < blocks.length; index++) {
            const block = blocks[index];
            table.innerHTML += block
        }
    })()

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, again. Can you please help me add a link to the "{name}" so when I click on the name it takes me to another page "name.html".

Comment: I tried so many times but It keeps failing, If you could help again me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you mean this?

<td><a href='name.html'>${name}</a></td>

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. would you mind helping me in the coming days because this is my school project and I am gonna need little help